# -webkit-appearance not disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to remove`-webkit-appearance:none;` through jQuery but nothing's working. I've tried the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery("select").removeAttr('style');
  jQuery("select").prop("style", "");
  jQuery("select").attr("style", "");
  jQuery("select").css("-webkit-appearance", "");
```

})

Also this one:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery("select:not([multiple])").removeAttr('style');
  jQuery("select:not([multiple])").prop("style", "");
  jQuery("select:not([multiple])").attr("style", "");
  jQuery("select:not([multiple])").css("-webkit-appearance", "");

})
```

Lastly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery("select#bulk_action_stat").removeAttr('style');
  jQuery("select#bulk_action_stat").prop("style", "");
  jQuery("select#bulk_action_stat").attr("style", "");
  jQuery("select#bulk_action_stat").css("-webkit-appearance", "");

})
```

The CSS:

```
select:not([multiple]) {
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -khtml-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 -ms-box-shadow: none;
 -o-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -khtml-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -ms-appearance: none;
 -o-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 background: url(../images/arrow.png) no-repeat right center;
 height: auto;
 border: 0;
 padding-right: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<form id="bulk_action_filter" class="form-inline" method="post">
    <select class="form-control" id="bulk_action_stat" name="bulk_action_stat">
        <option value="">Bulk Actions</option>
        <option value="trash">Move To Trash</option>
        <option value="wc-processing">Mark Processing</option>
        <option value="wc-on-hold">Mark On-Hold</option>
        <option value="wc-completed">Mark Complete</option>
        <option value="wc-delivered">Mark Delivered</option>
    </select>
    <input form="bulk_action_filter" type="submit" name="filter_bulk_actions" class="check-all filter-button" value="Apply" "/>
</form>
```

My goal is to remove that part so that my select dropdown will show the arrow down symbol or 'caret'.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

-Eli

Comment: You may want to look at your browser's developer tools, specifically all the errors reported in the JavaScript console (press F12 in most browsers, and navigate to the console).

Comment: `jQuery("select")removeAttr(style);` is the one blocking the rest, since `style` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys! I have corrected my syntax so no errors can be seen in console. But it's still not working. (I'll update the codes above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides correcting your CSS which is the valid approach you should take, if you ***have*** to do it through jQuery use

```
jQuery("#bulk_action_stat").css("appearance", "menulist-button");
```

jQuery is smart enough to apply the correct vendor prefix for it.
(*if you only want to fix it for webkit browsers though, then use*)

```
jQuery("#bulk_action_stat").css("-webkit-appearance", "menulist-button");
```

(*the actual selector i used is unimportant, all your selectors would have worked*)

Comment: Thanks @Gaby! Both of them worked but I chose the first one so it will be applied to all (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @jeepers_creepers Yes it will apply to all browsers that support the `appearance` property regardless of prefix. (*keep in mind that `appearance` is a non-standard property*)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in this line:

```
jQuery("select")removeAttr(style);
```

`style` (note that you are using a variable) is not defined (at least in the scope you are showing us)

Simply use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("select:not([multiple])").css("-webkit-appearance", "");
})
```

Comment: I also tried both inline and through a different file but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a class `.webkit-appearance`, which overwrites the css with an `!important`, and assign it with jquery.

CSS:

```
.webkit-appearance {
    -webkit-appearance: somevalue !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("select:not([multiple])").addClass('webkit-appearance');
})
```

Comment: Hi @jeffrey-roosendaal! Thanks for the suggestion. But my goal is to completely remove `-webkit-appearance: none;`. I've looked for the values for -webkit-appearance but there's nothing that I need. I also tested replacing `none` with other values available but nothing's working as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using plain JavaScript without the usage of *jquery*.

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("select")).forEach(function(el, i) {
          el.style.webkitAppearance = "none";
});
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('select').removeClass('-webkit-appearance')
```

or maybe:

```
$('select').each(function(index,item){
$(item).removeClass('-webkit-appearance')
})
```